# Bootstrap Multiselect Button Width Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I have used Multiselect of Bootstrap.

My issue is when I select item from options. If name is too long then button width is also increased.

[image]

How do I handle Button width after selecting options.

Comment: I tried with that before. Carat img is not displaying.

Comment: max width with overflow:hidden?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bootstrap, but in HTML you can place the <select> in a <div> and set the max-width of the <div> and use overflow: hidden of the <select>. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/80Ljcbhy/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code.

You can set max-width as you want in css.

**Javascript:**

```
 $('#yourXYZID').multiselect({
    buttonText: function(options) 
    {
        var retStr = "";
        if (options.length === 0) {
           retStr = "None selected";
        } else if(options.length <=3){
           var textArray = [];
           $.each(options,function(key,value){
               textArray.push($.trim($(value).html()));
           });
           retStr = "<div class='pull-left restricted'>"+textArray.join(",")+"</div>";
        } else {
           retStr = options.length+" selected";
        }
        return retStr+" <b class='caret'></b>";
    }
 });
```

**CSS:**

```
.multiselect.dropdown-toggle.btn.btn-default > div.restricted {
    margin-right: 5px;
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Adding explanations on the snippet could have been so helpful.

Answer (score 3):

`.multiselect` gives you a parameter called `buttonWidth`. This will keep the width wider when nothing is selected as well. You can put a % in there as well. You can set the width like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#yourcontrol').multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '100px'
        });
        //caret is in the middle, switch it to right
        $(".caret").css('float', 'right');
        $(".caret").css('margin', '8px 0');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another work around is that in the "buttonText" function in the bootstrap-multiselect.js file, we can set the button text length and then return like this:

```
if(selected.length>20){ 
   return selected.substr(0, 20); //if the text is too long, then this if statement will be executed
 }
else{
   return selected.substr(0, selected.length - this.delimiterText.length);
 }

/*Bootstrap adds extra characters for the selected option.For example: the length of the option 'peter' will actually be 14 because of the delimiter and extra spaces. So you may want to set a bigger number in the if statement*/
```

Note: In the actual code, the return statement is like below:

```
return selected.substr(0, selected.length - this.delimiterText.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it a quicker way I believe.
so you have your multiselect instantiation like this:

```
$('#anyID').multiselect({
```

and then some properties like

```
maxHeight:'300px'
```

well if you want to change button width upon a certain event. Do this:

```
buttonWidth:function(){             
     if(something happens) 
                    return '300px';  //  value chosen randomly
                else
                    return "150px";  //  value chosen randomly
    },
```

and that way you would have

**FINAL MULTISELECT**

```
 $('#anyID').multiselect({      

    maxHeight:'300px',
    buttonWidth:function(){             
     if(something happens) 
                    return '300px';  //  value chosen randomly
                else
                    return "150px";  //  value chosen randomly
    },
 )};
```